# How the process parameters changes with the length of data aggregation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, autoregressive, aggregation, parameterization

Is there any general relationship for a process(e.g. ARMA, O-U process) applied to financial data over different time intervals. e.g.In this question there is an answer telling the O.P. to aggregate his hourly data to obtain daily data and re-estimate the parameters because the dynamics of an hourly process can be very different from daily. How the process parameters changes with the length of data aggregation? How will parameters  get affected if one has a daily dataset for a very long period of time and start aggregating over a week? Kindly illustrate. Thanks

Comment: There is an article by Andrea Silvestrini and David Veridas from the Bank of Italy [Temporal aggregation of univariate and multivariate time series models: A survey](https://ideas.repec.org/p/bdi/wptemi/td_685_08.html). It goes directly on the issue of aggregation of ARIMA processes and impact on the parameter values.